# Point in OBB (Oriented Bounding Box) algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

Given a center point, width, height and angle forming an OBB, how can I find if a given point P is inside the OBB?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I take it that the wrinkle in your problem is that the bounding box can be rotated?  If so, the easiest solution to me seems to be to do all calculations in the rotated coordinate plane, centered on the center of the bounding box.

To calculate the coordinates of the point relative to these axes:

```
newy = sin(angle) * (oldy - centery) + cos(angle) * (oldx - centerx);
newx = cos(angle) * (oldx - centerx) - sin(angle) * (oldy - centery);
```

(you may need to adjust this depending on how *angle* is supposed to be measured, I'll leave that to you, since you didn't specify)

Then hit test, the normal way:

```
return (newy > centery - height / 2) && (newy < centery + height / 2) 
    && (newx > centerx - width / 2) && (newx < centerx + width / 2);
```

Comment: If my center point is 0,50, with width of 2 and my hit test point is 0,50 then this fails because the angle of the box will be 90 degrees, and 0,50 rotated by -90 which will no longer be within the box?

Answer (score 1):

You could transform the coordinates of your test point (via a transformation matrix) into a rotated coordinate system based on the angle of the bounding box.

At this stage it should just be an axis-aligned point-in-rectangle test, i.e. compare against `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax`. In the rotated coordinate system `xmin, xmax = xmid -+ width/2` and `ymin, ymax = ymid -+ height/2`.

Hope this helps.