# geom2d - oriented bounding box

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I calculated a rectangle (that does not need to be axis aligned) in an image and now want to check which pixel are inside that rectangle.
I believe the best way is to rotate each point in the image around the center point of the rectangle, such that the bounding box is axis aligned in the "new image". Then, we can quite easily check if a point is inside the rectangle or not.

I tried achieving this, by calculating an oriented bounding box with the geom2d package for my rectangle, which also gives us "the orientation of the length axis. Orientation is counted in degrees, counter-clockwise."

Up to now, I have not been able to understand exactly how the angle is defined. If I do the following:

```
obox1 = orientedBox([1 3; 4 1; 12 3; 9 5]);
obox2 = orientedBox([12 8; 9 10; 20 2; 24 3]);
figure;
isInside =  false(15,25);
imshow(isInside);hold on;
drawOrientedBox(obox1, 'green');
drawOrientedBox(obox2, 'red');
```

I get

[image]

with angle of green box = 14.03° and angle of red box = 154.98°. How do these values need to be interpreted?

Link to geom2d package:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7844-geom2d/content/geom2d/geom2d/orientedBox.m

Comment: Would you be able to create a binary mask for each rectangle, and simply check to see if the co-ordinate you want to check evaluates to `true` in the mask?  If you can do it this way, then I can whip up some code for you in no time.  FWIW, I don't think using rotations of any kind are necessary.  Also, with regards to the angles in your image, my best guess is that those represent clockwise angles, using the east as the origin.  So the green box has an angle of 14 degrees rotated clockwise.  Same for the red box too with its 154 degree rotation.

Comment: Searched a bit and it seemed rotations are the way to go, e.g., here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328424/point-in-obb-oriented-bounding-box-algorithm However, I haven't been able to make it work so far. For the green box I checked the angle between the line through (1,1) and (2,1) and the upper edge and I think  it was sth like 6°. But you are right, with a mask it should also work. Question is, how to create one. I could find all pixels and the lines and use imfill :)

Comment: I found the matlab function poly2mask, which does what we want. However, this requires the image processing toolbox

Comment: Are you not allowed to use the IPT?

Comment: yes, i luckily am. I justed wanted to note it for people who might not be.

Comment: OK cool. In that case, assuming that your rectangles are all connected, use `bwlabel` to find unique IDs for each region, then create binary masks for each of them individually. Then you can loop through them all and see if the pixel is contained in any of the regions